# Getting 403 Client error: Forbidden when trying to delete/update sets using python SoundCloud API

Tags: python, soundcloud

I'm developing a python app for managing playlists(sets). This app needs to create/update/delete sets using the SoundCloud API.

It's ok to create set using API. But when i'm trying to modify or delete created playlists, Im getting  403 Client Error: Forbidden.

I used "Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen" section from API docs.

Here is my code:

```
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='MY_ID', client_secret='MY_SECRET', username='NAME', password='PASS')
client.post('/playlists', playlist={'title': 'Test playlist', 'sharing': 'public', 'tracks': [], 'permalink': 'test-playlist'})
client.delete('/playlists/test-playlist')
```

And im getting the following exception on delete:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 130, in _request
    return wrapped_resource(make_request(method, url, kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 190, in make_request
    result.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 683, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden
```

Also Im getting the same exceptions whet trying to add tracks to playlist

```
client.put('/playlists/test-playlist', playlist={'tracks': tracks})
```

where tracks is:

```
[{'id': 57417403}, {'id': 100249929}, {'id': 37964083}]
```